# how to save results of two statement without defining extra array

Tags: python

I am comparing two arrays in python with if statement and elif statement, results should be saved in an other array, to avoid overwriting, I am using append., but I have to save results of these two statement without adding third array!
How I can append results of if statement to elif statement, with adhere to sequence of occurrence and without defining another array!

```
a = [[[1,20],[2,20],[3,20],[4,20],[5,20],[7,20],[5,20],[9,20],[11,20]]]

b = [[[1,20],[2,20],[3,20],[4,20],[6,20],[7,20],[8,20],[9,20],[10,20]]]

c = []


for i in range(0,len(b)):

 for j in range(0,len(b[i])):

      if a[i][j][0] == b[i][j][0]:

           c.append(b[i][j])

      elif a[i][j][0] == 5:

            c.append(b[i][j]) 
 print c
```

In this code I defined array "c" to save results of if statement and elif statement, but I need to append results of if statement to elif statement, without defining array c, and be able to make a print below elif!
can someone help me to solve this issue!?

Comment: I think you are missing a couple of square brackets in a and b

Comment: Do you want to use `print`?

Comment: actually I want to save results of if statement and elif statement, but results should be saved on elif

Comment: No, the brackets are correct!

Comment: You can already make somthing without elif...like `if((a==b)or(a==5))` because the treatment is the same. Not sure you can do it without a third array, because Your need to store and you can't store inside a data you are readding

Comment: Pretty sure you miss the last square on b :).

Comment: please be clear on what you need? you want to append results of if to results of elif? you don't want to use an additional array?

Comment: `>>> b = [[[1,20],[2,20],[3,20],[4,20],[6,20],[7,20],[8,20],[9,20],[10,20]]`
`...` python disagrees that the brackets are correct.

Comment: sorry, I edited it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a list comprehension to process it all in one statement:

```
>>> a = [[[1,20],[2,20],[3,20],[4,20],[5,20],[7,20],[5,20],[9,20],[11,20]]]
>>> b = [[[1,20],[2,20],[3,20],[4,20],[6,20],[7,20],[8,20],[9,20],[10,20]]]
>>>
>>> print([bitem 
           for (aitem, bitem) in zip(a[0], b[0])
           if bitem[0] == aitem[0] or aitem[0] == 5] )
[[1, 20], [2, 20], [3, 20], [4, 20], [6, 20], [7, 20], [8, 20], [9, 20]]
>>>
```

Of course this *does* create another list, it just doesn't name it.  Or store it. Or let you do anything useful with it.

Is there a reason you don't want to create a new list with your results?

Answer (score 1):

As @Minirock said in comments, you can filter using a single if/elif statement `if a==b or a==5`.

If you want to loop over the lists you need to store your comparison results into a third array `c`.

The only way to not create a third list is to make it "functional" like so:

```
flatten = lambda l: (item for sublist in l for item in sublist)
print filter(bool, map(lambda (x, y): y if x[0] == y[0] or x[0] == 5 else None, zip(flatten(a), flatten(b))))
```

Please read the following resources in Python's standard documentation: 
[map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map),[filter function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map),[bool function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map),[zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map),

P.s: when you make for loops, in Python, you can do it as so:

```
for sublists in zip(a, b):
    for (item_a, tem_b) in sublist:
        if item_a[0] == item_b[0]:
           ...etc...
```

avoid accessing lists by index when iterating as much as possible.